# Evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+...+\frac{n-1}{n!}$.

Tags: summation

Sadly, Google does not allow me to search for factorials, so I could not solve this problem by Google searching.

Evaluate the sum $\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+...+\frac{n-1}{n!}$.

Comment: Do you really want an expression for this finite sum, or for its limit as $n\to\infty$? I think the latter is possible. I'm not so sure about the former.

Comment: Do you consider "google searching" a form of problem solving?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Fair enough...this was a bad question. I tried to solve the problem by hand, but for some reason the solution escaped me and I overestimated the problem's difficulty, so I came here.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Write $\displaystyle\frac{n - 1}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!}$ and add these up!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Here are the first few partial sums.

$S_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

$S_2 = \frac{5}{6}$

$S_3 = \frac {23}{24}$

$S_4 = \frac{119}{120}$

Do you see a pattern? If so, use that pattern to reverse-engineer a solution.

**Hint 2**: $$\frac{n-1}{n!} = \frac{n}{n!} - \frac{1}{n!}$$